# build.rs doesn't generate files

Tags: rust, grpc, rust-cargo

I have a rust project in which I have a build.rs. The contents of build.rs is

```
fn main() {
    // Build helloworld
    tower_grpc_build::Config::new()
       .enable_server(true)
       .enable_client(true)
       .build(
           &["src/proto/helloworld/helloworld.proto"],
           &["src/proto/helloworld"],
       )
       .unwrap_or_else(|e| panic!("protobuf compilation failed: {}", e));
       println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=proto/helloworld/helloworld.proto"); 
   }
```

My Cargo.toml

```
build="build.rs"
```

This entry is under package.

And in my main.rs

```
pub mod items {
   include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/helloworld.rs"));
}

fn main() {
   println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

OUT_DIR is set to the src directory of the project.

What did I miss here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "OUT_DIR is set to the src directory of the project" - that's not normal, it should be set by Cargo to the corresponding "target" directory. How do you ensure this, anyway?

Comment: @Cerberus, I believe you are right. OUT_DIR should not be set. The include and concat micros should just take care of it.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. To make it complete, provide your entire Cargo.toml. To make it minimal, replace the usages of `tower_grpc` with plain file creation. Create a brand new Cargo project that reproduces the issue with the bare minimum, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!